# Quickblox android - Audio call crash before call activity started

Tags: java-native-interface, quickblox

Audio call crash before call activity started.

```
06-24 10:28:11.336: D/RTCClient(30532): Create new session
06-24 10:28:11.336: D/dalvikvm(30532): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/packagename-3/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so 0x42a22eb0
06-24 10:28:11.341: D/dalvikvm(30532): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/packagename-3/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so 0x42a22eb0
06-24 10:28:11.341: D/EglBase(30532): SDK version: 19
06-24 10:28:11.346: D/WEBRTCN(30532): SetRenderAndroidVM
06-24 10:28:11.346: E/rtc(30532): #
06-24 10:28:11.346: E/rtc(30532): # Fatal error in ../../talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/jni_helpers.cc, line 267
06-24 10:28:11.346: E/rtc(30532): # Check failed: ret
06-24 10:28:11.346: E/rtc(30532): # 
06-24 10:28:11.346: E/rtc(30532): #
06-24 10:28:11.346: D/dalvikvm(30532): [SWE] ### S.LSI JIT optimization list BEGIN ###
06-24 10:28:11.346: D/dalvikvm(30532): [SWE] ### S.LSI JIT optimization list END ###
06-24 10:28:11.346: A/libc(30532): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00007744 (code=-6), thread 30532 (packagename)
```

Error occurs at the line where

```
QBRTCSession newSessionWithOpponents = QBRTCClient.getInstance().createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);
```

in method

```
public void addConversationFragmentStartCall(List<Integer> opponents,
            QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType qbConferenceType,
            Map<String, String> userInfo) {

        // init session for new call
        try {


            QBRTCSession newSessionWithOpponents = QBRTCClient.getInstance().createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);
            Log.d("Crash", "addConversationFragmentStartCall. Set session " + newSessionWithOpponents);
            setCurrentSession(newSessionWithOpponents);

            ConversationFragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList(ApplicationSingleton.OPPONENTS,
                    new ArrayList<Integer>(opponents));
            bundle.putInt(ApplicationSingleton.CONFERENCE_TYPE, qbConferenceType.getValue());
            bundle.putInt(START_CONVERSATION_REASON, StartConversetionReason.OUTCOME_CALL_MADE.ordinal());
            bundle.putString(CALLER_NAME, DataHolder.getUserNameByID(opponents.get(0)));

            for (String key : userInfo.keySet()) {
                bundle.putString("UserInfo:" + key, userInfo.get(key));
                Toast.makeText(this, userInfo.get(key), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }



            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, CONVERSATION_CALL_FRAGMENT).commit();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apparently webrtc is [failing to obtain a global reference](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/trunk/talk/+/3412b4458d5507de944fb3df110a014cc5213ced/app/webrtc/java/jni/jni_helpers.cc) for a Java object. You might want to include some code in your question to show what you're doing when this happens, as well as the full native stacktrace. You might also want to check the [list of reported bugs](http://www.webrtc.org/report-bug) for webrtc (and possibly report your own).

Comment: Before the new library, the project uses quickblox 2.0, then i migrated to 2.25.  The cause might be the change  from old armeabi-v7a .so  to new .so file.  In libs folder, i remove previous .so to new one.  Should i upgrade in other places ? maybe the previous .so file is cached somewhere in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake. Create session method used in application was old. The latest jar recognise the create session method but video call webRTC sample don't. By implementing new session style, audio call works successfully. Thank you.